# sapply() with with vector of values instead of 1:n

Tags: r, sapply, subset

I would like to have an `sapply()` statement of the following form:

```
a <- c(4, 9, 20, 3, 10, 30)
sapply(c(a), function(x) b[x,2] - b[x,1])
```

Normally instead of `c(a)` I would have `1:x`, however now I would like to go through only the values specified in `a`. Is this possible?

**Update:** The point is not what goes after `function(x)` - that is only intended as an example.

Comment: Does `b[a,2] - b[a,1]` not work?

Comment: and what is wrong with what you have? It works perfectly, as intended.

Comment: `sapply( a , print )` for example. You will see that it works, exactly as you expect. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: the question is not about how to solve this toy subtraction problem, the question is how to use sapply to iterate through a vector of arbitrary numbers instead of a 1:n sequence

Comment: and the answer is *just like you did*.

Comment: I agree with @flodel. `a` works, unless your `a` is a _position_ of certain numbers in another vector (say `1:n`). If that's the case, I see how we were thrown off of our game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (see `?sapply`), the first argument (`X`) to `sapply` can be a vector. There is no restriction on the vector saying it has to be of the form `1:x`. So your current code should loop correctly over the values of `a`:

```
sapply(c(a), function(x) b[x,2]-b[x,1])
```

Note, that you don't need `c(a)` - just `a` is fine:

```
sapply(a, function(x) b[x,2]-b[x,1])
```

If for some reason you did not communicate to us this does not work, it is not a problem with `sapply` but with the function you are passing to it.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very clear what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think that you need `sapply`.

```
a <- c(4, 9, 20, 3, 10, 30)
b <- data.frame(x = 1:30, y = sqrt(1:30))
b[a, 2] - b[a, 1]
## [1]  -2.000000  -6.000000 -15.527864  -1.267949  -6.837722 -24.522774
```

Comment: all I want is sapply to use as 'x' the values specified in 'a' instead of iterating through a 1:n interval

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to perform the function only on the values specified in `a` but keep the original values otherwise? Because you don't provide `b` I show another example here.

```
v <- 1:40
a<-c(4,9,20,3,10,30)
sapply(v, function(x) if(x %in% a){x+1} else {x})
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right (that they are after values and not indices). However, they coincide in your example...`identical(v,seq_along(v))`

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't matter for the function. You can replace `v` with another vector.